# Howto find Tomcat current thread count

Tags: tomcat

On my Linux server I run tomcat as root and when I run `ps aux` it gives the following output.

```
root     25667  0.1 29.2 4574004 306980 ?      Sl   Apr27  33:57 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file...
```

Thre is only parent process, but when I run `htop` I can see all other child process (which are threads?). Sample output for a few lines given below.

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command                                                              
25668 root       15   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:01.23 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25669 root       18   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:54.84 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25670 root       15   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:00.25 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25671 root       15   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:00.54 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25672 root       18   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:00.00 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25673 root       15   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:17.96 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25674 root       15   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:20.01 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
25675 root       19   0 4466M  299M 14208 S  0.0 29.3  0:00.00 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/t
```

So I want to get child process list with a single command. I set maxThreads to 200 in config file, and want to check current thread count by counting child threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy enough to do: `ps -eLf | grep java`

Might have to adjust (grep can be refined to get what you're looking for).

Comment: Is there a command to list the threads running on the http ports of tomcat, other than the tomcat GUI(http://192.168.5.68:10181/manager/status)?

Answer (score 5):

You can launch:

```
ps -o nlwp PID
```

(PID will be the pid of your process)

nlwp = number of lightweight process

Comment: Do this really give numberof active threads ?

Comment: Yes. NLWP means number of light-weight processes which is precisely the number of threads the process is currently using.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask running threads (which are actively doing work), and not the idle ones

Answer (score 3):

If you have a JDK installed, one very useful way of monitoring this (and the various heaps sizes) in real-time is `jconsole`, which is a GUI program (if you have `javac`, you should also have this). There are also things like `jstat` and `jinfo` and others. To benefit from jconsole, you may need to enable JMX (this can also be done for remote connections). You'll need to run these tools as the same user that is running the JVM you want to inspect.

If you're using `top` or `htop`, then you can type `H` (capital) to toggle display of threads. Its worth looking at the various top keystrokes.